# Is it possible to put the clock on the launcher bar if its at the bottom? The old windows style basically?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, clock

See image.  The launcher (Ubuntu dock) is on the bottom of the screen.  I'm looking to add the clock to that location.
[image: Launcher on the bottom of the screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can the **[Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)** GNOME shell extension.

> This extension moves the dash into the gnome main panel so that the application launchers and system tray are combined into a single panel, similar to that found in KDE Plasma and Windows 7+. A separate dock is no longer needed for easy access to running and favorited applications.
>
> [image]

This extension also lets you place the panel at the bottom instead on the top.

Refer to this to learn more about installing and configuring GNOME shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530)

Comment: Perfect.  even better than I thought.  Thank you!